# Submitting multidimensional forms with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, sql, forms

I have a very large form with numerous fields being generated from PHP.

For instance I have a `<select>` element where all of the options are being pulled from a database with SQL/PHP.

I want to be able to have the next option in the form dependent on the option chosen above.

However I do not want to submit the form in its entirety until all fields are filled in.

This is for an Ecommerce site, for a simple example selling custom tshirts with writing on them:

->User has an `<input>` for custom text

->User has a `<select>` for size/colour

->User then has pricing options based on selection above

I need to be able to get the options selected in the first two inputs to determine the third but do not want the form to submit until all options are filled in.

Is this possible? I was thinking that I would have to have individual forms for each element, for example the text field would have its own form which would return false I can then fire an onchange event in JS and get the value and add this to a hidden input in an overall master form that submits at the very end.

Comment: Try to do some Ajax.

Comment: actually not sure if using js like this would work as I need to be able to do a look up in sql for prices based on size and will not be able to use the js variable to query the db

Comment: Yes Ajax is the key here.Use Ajax

Comment: Actually, if you are expecting a full solution here then you are at a wrong place. Please post some of the work done by you...

Comment: @Vickrant Thanks for the comments. Not expecting a full solution. Was just hoping to be pointed in the right direction so I could try figure it out myself.

Comment: Any time dude happy coding.